# why play store not showing localized description and screenshots of my App?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I have published my App on Google Play Store. Now I added 4 languages English, Hindi, Tamil and Telugu in my App. I uploaded all the translations and also localized screenshot through the store listing option in Play Store.

Now on play store app is displaying fine over English and Hindi language phones. But when I searched my app on a phone who's language was set to Tamil then I find it is showing everything like description, screenshots in english. Same is happening for Telugu.

Could you please suggest me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Play Store check every of them in separate date wait i have same issue it's solved soon

I localized my app with 9 language after 1 month my app enroll correctly

hope it's help

Comment: Will I get any notification or email from play store when they done?