# Android - Play Store not showing localized app details & graphics

Tags: android, localization, google-play, persian, localizable.strings

We have uploaded app on app store having EN and FA (Persian) language support and app is all working fine on both languages (it's on material design and uses string.xml).

We have also added necessary graphics and translated text on play store for EN and FA but play store only shows english. If device language is set to FA then play store does work in FA but app description and graphics all are in English only. Is there anything else needs to be done apart from store listing in both languages?

I [visited this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43222292/why-play-store-not-showing-localized-description-and-screenshots-of-my-app) thread but doesn't help me much. It's already been more than one month we have listed both languages.

Please help as it's very important for us to list in proper languages based on device language.